# Splitting a string with elements containing delimiter

Tags: c#, regex, split

I have a string that looks like this:

```
'xxx',1,'yyy',0,'zzz,www',0,'','etc'
```

I would like to split it by comma but problem is with elements (strings) containing it.
I can parse this string element by element but it would be better to use something like Regex.

If element is type of string it is always in quotes.

Expected result:

```
xxx
1
yyy
0
zzz,www
0
<empty>
etc
```

Oryginal string for splitting:
DA,'SHT-1',3000.00,1500.00,1.00,1,3000.00,1500.00,'1.4301-10',7.900,
*  '1.4301','MAX,MIN-500','C'

Code:

```
string SampleText = @"DA,'SHT-1',3000.00,1500.00,1.00,1,3000.00,1500.00,'1.4301-10',7.900,
*  '1.4301','MAX,MIN-500','C'";

// [1] Prepare for splitting (remove new lines, white spaces, etc);
SampleText = Regex.Replace(SampleText, @"\r\n?|\n|\*|\s", "");

// [2] replacing commas
MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(SampleText , "\'.*?\'");
foreach (Match mh in mc)
{
  if (mh.Value.Contains(','))
  {
    SampleText = SampleText.Replace(mh.Value, mh.Value.Replace(",", "_"));
  }
}

// splitting
string[] progHeader = SampleText.Split(new char[] { ',' });
```

What do I need is to eliminate step with replacing commas.

Comment: Use an available tool to parse CSV instead of reinventing the wheel. I can suggest this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader It also supports quoting characters.

Comment: shouldn't your expected result have `'`s in it?

Comment: You did not search MSDN. MSDN has already shown examples for such.

Comment: It is not about reinventing the wheel - I have a workaround in 5 lines of code using Regex but it needs walking through all Regex matches. My point is to use only Regex once.

Comment: "I have a workaround" is exactly about reinventing the wheel.  It's CSV, so use a CSV parser.

Comment: What you're asking is the same as "I need to add two numbers together, but my code doesn't work for when a number contains a zero.  I've written a five-line work around, but it means checking every digit.  How do I fix it?"  Reading CSV is a problem with an already written solution, exactly the same as adding two numbers is.

Incidentally, using a CSV parser *will* solve your "What do I need is to eliminate step with replacing commas" problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using something like this

```
    public static String[] SplitCsv(String value) {
      if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, value))
        return null;

      const Char quotation = '\'';
      const Char separator = ',';

      List<String> result = new List<String>();

      Boolean inQuotation = false;
      Boolean isStarted = false;

      StringBuilder Sb = new StringBuilder();

      foreach (Char Ch in value) {
        if (inQuotation) {
          Sb.Append(Ch);
          inQuotation = Ch != quotation;

          continue;
        }

        if (Ch == separator) {
          result.Add(Sb.ToString());
          Sb.Length = 0;
          isStarted = true;
        }
        else {
          Sb.Append(Ch);
          isStarted = false;
          inQuotation = Ch == quotation;
        }
      }

      if (isStarted || (Sb.Length > 0))
        result.Add(Sb.ToString());

      return result.ToArray();
    }

  ....

  var test1 = SplitCsv("1,2,3");   // <- ["1", "2", "3"]
  var test2 = SplitCsv("1,2,");    // <- ["1", "2", ""]
  var test3 = SplitCsv("1,'2',3"); // <- ["1", "'2'", "3"]
  var test4 = SplitCsv("1,'2,3'"); // <- ["1", "'2,3'"]
  var test5 = SplitCsv("1,''");    // <- ["1", "''"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If this was only as an exercise: `/('[^']*')|([^,']+)/g` looks like this will do (but match, not split).