# Split line from txt file

Tags: c#, split, string-formatting

I am trying to split each line from a text file

Each line is something like this:

```
string text=3,"dac","fsdf,sdf","DdsA 102-13",62.560000000000002,"1397","bes","165/70/R13",945,1380,"Break",10
```

I need to split it and need to obtain these 12 columns.
Is there a way to split it and get 12 columns? as you can see there are parts which contain also "," (comma)

Comment: So you know that you're lookig for `Split`, have you found anything? This requirement is not particularly groundbreaking.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18228982/splitting-a-string-with-elements-containing-delimiter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 public static String[] SplitCsv(String value)
    {            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, value))
            return null;
        const Char quotation = '\"';
        const Char separator = ',';
        List<String> result = new List<String>();
        Boolean inQuotation = false;
        Boolean isStarted = false;
        StringBuilder Sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (Char Ch in value)
        {
            if (inQuotation)
            {
                Sb.Append(Ch);
                inQuotation = Ch != quotation;
                continue;
            }

            if (Ch == separator)
            {
                result.Add(Sb.ToString());
                Sb.Length = 0;
                isStarted = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Sb.Append(Ch);
                isStarted = false;
                inQuotation = Ch == quotation;
            }
        }

        if (isStarted || (Sb.Length > 0))
            result.Add(Sb.ToString());

        return result.ToArray();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
string s = "3,dac,fsdfsdf,DdsA 102-13,62.560000000000002,1397,bes,165/70/R13,945,1380,Break,10"
string[] words = s.Split(',');
foreach (string word in words)
{
    Console.WriteLine(word);
}
```

The string.Split() method will return an array of strings, and via the parameter you can specify the character by which it should split the original string.

**Update:**

Okay, please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3776617/1552016).
Slightly modified code from there:

```
public IEnumerable<string> SplitCSV(string input)
{
    Regex csvSplit = new Regex("(?:^|,)(\"(?:[^\"]+|\"\")*\"|[^,]*)", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    foreach (Match match in csvSplit.Matches(input))
    {
        yield return match.Value.TrimStart(',');
    }
}

string s = "3,\"dac\",\"fsdf,sdf\",\"DdsA 102-13\",62.560000000000002,\"1397\",\"bes\",\"165/70/R13\",945,1380,\"Break\",10";
var words = SplitCSV(s);
foreach (string word in words)
{
    Console.WriteLine(word); 
}
```

On how to apply this to all lines in a file:

```
var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"inputfile.txt");
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    var wordsInLine = SplitCSV(line);
    // do whatever you want with the result...
}
```

Comment: yes I did this, but in some parts it's possible to be something like "asdasd,asda" and so it will split one more time.

Comment: That was just a sample line, OP wants all fields of all lines.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I thought the question was about splitting one line into 12 columns, and actually I still think so :)

Comment: But OP mentioned that this is just a sample: _"I am trying to split each line from a text file, each line is something like this: ..."_

Comment: I really don't like to be the kind of person that I am right now, but if you read just two more sentences: _"Is there a way to split it and get 12 columns?"_ This is the only question in the text :)

Answer (score -1):

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"textfile.txt");
string result[][];

foreach (string line in lines)
{
    string[] splitedLine = line.Split(',');
    result.Add(splitedLine);
}
```

result is an array with all you splited line (your line could have different number of words)

Then, you can save into a text file or do what you want